# iOS: will storing a block, and a method to call it, in a subclass of UILabel cause trouble?

Tags: ios, subclass, objective-c-blocks

So, I've been looking around at how to pass a block to a button as a selector, and the answers seem more complicated than I need.

If I subclass UILabel with a method called `doBlock;` and a block variable called `blockToDo`, and all the method does is call `blockToDo ();` couldn't I do something like:

```
myLabel.blockToDo = ^myBlock;   
[myButton addTarget: myLabel action: @selector (doBlock) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or is that going to get me into some kind of trouble I'm not aware of?

Edit: So, there's two things here: what I really wanted to do, and the answer to the question I asked. They're different things.

Another way to phrase my question might be to split it in two. One half would be "if I want to add a simple method to UILabel, can I just subclass it and add that method, or are there a bunch of other things that a subclass of UILable is obligated to do?" The other half would be "adding a `doBlock;` method to a subclass seems to be the easiest way to pass a block as a selector, but all the suggestions on these boards seem to be to define a whole new class for that purpose, which seems like a lot of extra work. Why?"

It seems like most people tackled that second question, which is understandable, because it's actually the more obvious part of the original question as stated.

But, as to what I really wanted to do: what I've ended up doing is defining a category that has a `doBlock;` method, and using [associative referencing](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/) to store a `^myBlock` ivar within the category. This is very versatile, because I can just use the category to tack a block onto any class and it will then respond to `@selector (doBlock)`.

So, I'm not sure how to wrap this up. The question I asked has been partially answered, but it turns out that what I really wanted to do isn't all that directly relevant to the question as formulated. How should I award a best answer?

Comment: As long as the property copies the block, no.

Comment: Is subclassing the UILabel a specific need? I'd just make a simple object that is a subclass of NSObject that has an invoke method to call the block.

Comment: @RyanPendleton: is there are reason people post answers as comments in stead of answers? If there's no downside for you, would you mind posting this as an answer, and we can discuss it there?

Comment: I'm not sure where to put this: I think what I want to do is actually use a category with a method that performs a block, and use an associative reference to store the block...

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like the following. You could additionally make a category that made this easier. Note that `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` does not retain the target.

Update: If you're using ARC, the best solution might be to make a category that assigns itself as an associated object. However, seeing as how long ago I originally wrote this answer, there are probably better solutions available.

```
BlockExecutor *executor = [BlockExecutor executorWithBlock:^(id sender) {

}];

[myButton addTarget:executor action:@selector(invokeWithSender:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

BlockExecutor.h

```
typedef void (^BlockExecutorBlock)(id);

@interface BlockExecutor : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, copy)BlockExecutorBlock block;

+ (BlockExecutor*)executorWithBlock:(BlockExecutorBlock)block;

@end
```

BlockExecutor.m

```
@implementation BlockExecutor
@synthesize block = _block;;

+ (BlockExecutor*)executorWithBlock:(BlockExecutorBlock)aBlock
{
    BlockExecutor *executor = [[BlockExecutor alloc] init];
    executor.block = aBlock;

    return [executor autorelease];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.block = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)invokeWithSender:(id)sender
{
    if(_block)
    {
        _block(sender);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You should add a nil check in `invokeWithSender:`: `if (_block) _block(sender);`

Comment: I dont' understand why you're passing (sender) to the block, and how the block is receiving (sender) in [myButton addTarget:executor action:@selector(invokeWithSender:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: UIKit does it for us automatically. According to the documentation, action: is an action message, and the selector documentation states: "All action messages take a single parameter, the id of the control device sending the message."

Comment: It's also important to note that addTarget: does not actually retain the target, so you'll want to retain the executor and release it when appropriate.

Comment: @RyanPendleton: even with ARC?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe won't "cause trouble" like a crash or a memory leak.

However, it is probably a violation of the MVC design pattern. Normally in MVC, a button (which is a view) sends a message to a controller.  Then the controller either updates the label (another view) directly (if the button action shouldn't change the model), or the controller modifies the model, which causes the label to be updated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily end up with a retain cycle with this approach. Say the block references the controller:

```
label.blockToDo = ^{
    [controller didTapLabel];
}
```

The block will retain the controller, so the controller can't be deallocated. Since the controller will never receive its final release, it won't remove its views, and the label won't release the callback block.

You can get around this by being careful about what's in the block, but I think it's cleaner to keep the block in your controller and invoke it via the selector attached to the label's target/action.